# How did Sherlock describe his father: a ____ par excellence

Tags: dialogue, elementary

On an episode of the show *Elementary*, Sherlock describes his father as "[something] par excellence". I can't remember what the [something] is. I used to just google Morland Holmes and the first thing up,  would have the quote. I have looked in Wikipedia, and TV fanatic. Unfortunately, I can't remember which episode it's in or the names of other places I have looked. I don't think there is anything else I can tell you.

Answer (score 3):

The dialogue you're looking for is:

> influence peddler par excellence

In fact, [it's quoted in the Sherlock Holmes wiki](http://bakerstreet.wikia.com/wiki/Morland_Holmes).

> He is described as an international consultant, and an "influence peddler par excellence".